# Unable to highlight quoted string using regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

The regex pattern works when I try it in regexr.com

```
pattern = %r{(["'])(?:\\\1|[^\1])*?\1}
string = %Q(var msg = 'hello' + 'world')
string.gsub(pattern, '<span>\1</span>')
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
"var msg = <span>'hello'</span> + <span>'world'</span>"
```

But instead I am getting:

```
# => "var msg = <span>'</span> + <span>'</span>"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to write `regex = /(["'])(?:\\\1|[^\1])*?\1/`, `string = "var msg = 'hello' + 'world'"`?

Comment: Yikes, you just selected the one and only answer offered so far, a mere 20 minutes after you posted. Quick-draw selections may discourage other, possibly better, answers, and short-circuit those still preparing answers. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection. The point is there's no rush to make a selection.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It may be simpler but that won't alone will solve the problem of OP

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thank you for your feedback, you can see I have a low rep and still learning as much from the community.I will keep your point in mind and review each answers more carefully now and in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you think you are printing and capturing wrong. It should be

```
pattern = %r{(["'])(\\\1|[^\1]*?)\1}
                      # ^^
                      # ||
   #(This will capture the string hello etc. which are after quotes) 
string = %Q(var msg = 'hello' + 'world')
string.gsub(pattern, '<span>\1\2\1</span>')
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/h5sGT6)**

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be clearer to use a regex that does not have capture groups.

```
r = /
    (?:'.+?') # match one or more of any character, lazily, surrounded by
              # single quotes, in a non-capture group
    |         # or
    (?:".+?") # match one or more of any character, lazily, surrounded by
              # double quotes, in a non-capture group
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

which you would normally see written

```
r = /(?:'.+?')|(?:".+?")/
```

Then

```
"var msg = 'hello' + 'world'".gsub(r) { |s| "<span>%s</span>" % s }
  #=> "var msg = <span>'hello'</span> + <span>'world'</span>" 
"var msg = \"hello\" + \"world\"".gsub(r) { |s| "<span>#{s}</span>" }
  #=> "var msg = <span>\"hello\"</span> + <span>\"world\"</span>" 
"var msg = 'It is my' + 'friend Bubba'".gsub(r) { |s| "<span>"+s+"</span>" }
  #=> "var msg = <span>'It is my'</span> + <span>'friend Bubba'</span>"
```

Comment: you are making an assumption that `hello` will always be in single quotes which is not the case as per OP

Comment: @rock321987, thanks. I missed that because it only can be inferred from the OP's regex. I modified my answer.